# JavaScript Watch removing watched value from object

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to watch an objects value, and if it changes, so some stuff..

So this is my object,

```
var list = [{
   object: undefined,
   index: 0,
   src: 'url here',
   active: { val: 0 }
}]
```

So I made active an additional object as I create a new object from the above, but make the `active` value the value from above, this keeps a reference of this object between the 2 objects.

```
var newList = [];
newList.push({
  object: undefined,
  index: 0,
  src: list[i].src,
  active: list[i].active // Use reference to old list
});
```

So i'm trying to watch the `active` value like so:

```
(list.active).watch('val', function() {
  if (list.active.val === 1) {
    console.log('active');
    list.object.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    console.log('not active');
    list.object.classList.remove('active');
  }
});
```

However it appears that when I watch this value it is being removed, as if I `console.log` out the `list`, then the value is  set to undefined! I'm changing the value of `list.active.val` after adding the watch events.

Here is the Polyfill i'm using for the watch functionality.

```
// object.watch
if (!Object.prototype.watch) {
  Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "watch", {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: false,
    value: function (prop, handler) {
      var oldval = this[prop],
          newval = oldval,
          getter = function () {
            return newval;
          },
          setter = function (val) {
           oldval = newval;
            return newval = handler.call(this, prop, oldval, val);
          };

      if (delete this[prop]) { // can't watch constants
        Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
          get: getter,
          set: setter,
          enumerable: true,
          configurable: true
        });
      }
    }
  });
}

// object.unwatch
if (!Object.prototype.unwatch) {
  Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "unwatch", {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: false,
    value: function (prop) {
      var val = this[prop];
      delete this[prop]; // remove accessors
      this[prop] = val;
    }
  });
}
```

**Edit 1**

Added the proxy-observe Polyfill however this doesn't appear to be watching still, I have added it like so:

```
list[0] = Object.observe(list[0], function(changeset) {
  console.log('changed');
});
```

`list[0].active` contains the object `{ val: 0 }`, so it should be observicing this object.

Not getting any errors, it's just doing nothing, ideas?

Comment: You access `list` as an array, but it isn't. Also I wonder what the variable `i` is.

Comment: Your `handler` should return the new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to implement a custom `watch/unwatch` features, 
`Ecmascript 2015` already provides a specific api:

#### [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

There are a plenty of polyfills to make it working on legacy browsers.

There was a proposal called `Object.Observe` to address what you need and you can find a `Proxy` porting here: https://github.com/anywhichway/proxy-observe

Follows a basic working example:

```js
// Your Observable target
const target = Object.create(null);

const observer = {
  set(target, key, value) {
    console.log(`Should we set '${value}' as value of '${key}' property?`)
    
    target[key] = value;
  },
};


const observable = new Proxy(target, observer);
observable.someKindOfProperty = 'Hello World';
```

Comment: That's quite a lengthy Polyfill however at 287 lines, which I would need as this will need to work on IE.

Comment: And what's the problem? Polyfilling is always better than custom implementations because it allows you to work with standard api and new browsers don't need polyfillis.

Comment: Ah true, I have made an edit to my post, can you please review.

Comment: please, have a look on how `Proxies` work: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy